App crashes when running Python code from Flutter/Native MACOS application
Backgroud
Running python code using Beeware - Briefcase tool and call Python code from Flutter/Native MACOS application.
Issue
The code runs completely fine on MAC machines powered with Intel processors but breaks on Apple processors. (Crashing on M1 and M2 processors)
How it’s implemented and what Root cause has been analyzed so far for Apple processors?
The Python code is hosted by making use of Uvicorn and since Unicorn keeps a hold of a Thread and never returns. So the same is executed on a background thread from Xcode making use of dispatch_queue
MacOS Code
- (void) trigger_python_main_init {
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
       [self python_main_init];
   });
}

The Python code further makes use of Pickle file which when loaded of a bigger size anything more than 1MB (for instance) creates this issue
Note: Smaller size files work fine.
with open(self.vocab_path, "rb") as handle:
           self.vocab = pickle.load(handle)
           self.vocab = {element: None for element in self.vocab}

When you run python code in man thread it works fine in M1 and M2 as well. Below code works fine
- (void) trigger_python_main_init {
   [self python_main_init];
}

We want to run the python code in a background thread/process as its a heavy processing task (Python code is responsible of hosting local webserver)
